# Connecting powered USB C hub to Surface pro 6

Tags: usb-3, usb-c, microsoft-surface-pro

I have Surface Pro 6 with single USB A 3.0 port. Can I connect USB C hub using USB C to USB A adapter to it and supply power to hub? Hub has power pass through PD connection. Will it damage mainboard?

Answer (score 0):

> I have Surface Pro 6 with single USB A 3.0 port. Can I connect USB C
> hub using USB C to USB A adapter to it and supply power to hub?

As is the case with many questions like this...

Yes, you can.  *No, you may not.*  Don't do it.

> Hub has power pass through PD connection. Will it damage mainboard?

It quite likely will.  The USB spec specifically disallows adapters to plug devices with captive USB-C cables into USB-A ports, likely because it can cause damage to computers.  Is it possible to design these adapters in a way to prevent such damage?  Yes, it is.  Why didn't they do it then?  I can only speculate.  In looking at how USB works there is no easy way to know what one intends to get out of putting a USB-C receptacle on a host with only USB-A ports.

A big problem is not just the direction of power flow.  USB-C allows power in both directions so it is possible with these adapters for a power supply to try to put power into the port while the host is trying to put power out, and do so at very different voltages.  There's supposed to be fuses to protect the ports from this but those fuses are not foolproof.  Even if the power is flowing in the right direction the USB-C spec allows for 3 amps while the original USB spec required only half an amp be supplied.  It's far too easy to blow fuses, or do permanent damage to something if the fuses don't open up fast enough.

I see questions like this quite often on the StackExchange sites and too many people suggesting these adapters, which is playing with fire.  That playing with fire comment may become literal in some cases.